# How to show jQuery DatePicker explicitly using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want the Datepicker to show on a particular event which can be triggered when a particular value is chosen in a drop down.

In other words I want to write an `onchange` function for the drop down and if the value matches, I could call the function to show the calendar. but the function `showDatepicker` as described in the docs page doesn't work:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/showDatepicker

Try running the following command in firebug console at the following page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```
$("#datepicker").showDatepicker();
```

It should work as described in the Docs, but it doesn't

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking... to attach a Datepicker widget to an element you use `$("#elementId").datepicker();`.

Comment: That I know I was asking how to display the calendar. bemace's answer does the trick. i.e, to use `$("#datepicker").datepicker("show");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use `$("#datepicker").datepicker("show");`